# Which printer driver should I use when there are many options available with the same name?

Tags: printer

In my specific case, I'm using an HP Color Laserjet Pro MFP M477fdw. I am having trouble, because depending on which driver I choose, different features are available (eg, I cannot print with duplex using the top option).

However, I have experienced this problem with other printers, too. The problem is that I do not know which one to choose, because there are many options with the same name. See the screenshot.

[image]

Which one do I choose? If I were to guess, one is for the M477dw, or the M477fdn, etc. etc. Is there a way to see the full name of the driver as well as any additional information about it? Or am I left guessing and checking until all the features work?

---

Additionally, I'm not sure I'm choosing the correct "network printer" option. When choosing the printer on my network list, I have two options for my printer, `HP Color Laserjet MFP M477fdw` and `HP Color Laserjet MFP M477fdw (49BC77)`

[image]

I do not know what 49BC77 means. I have been selecting the option above it before adding the driver. Does this have an effect?

Thanks!